# User timing in Google analytics data is not showing

Tags: reactjs, performance, google-analytics, react-redux

From my react application I enable debug mode for google analytics
and successfully event are getting triggered but it is not showing in Google analytics

```
ga("send", {hitType: "timing", timingCategory: "Performance Callback Server Latency", timingVar: "Campaign", timingValue: 0.9950000094249845})

[react-ga] with fieldObject: {"hitType":"timing","timingCategory":"Performance Callback Server Latentcy","timingVar":"Campaign","timingValue":0.9950000094249845}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution , it is accepting only integer value not decimal and I was passing decimal value

Answer (score 0):

### siteSpeedSampleRate

You probably have too low traffic on your page. In that case, increase siteSpeedSampleRate trackers configration.

Default value is **1**, representing **1%** of users that tracks their timing into analytics.

Increase this value to **10%**.

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', {'siteSpeedSampleRate': 10});
```

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#siteSpeedSampleRate